# Rails 3 multiple format validations for the same field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a model has two format validations on the same field, what does it take for the model to be valid? Does the field have to be matched by both validations or does it only need to be matched by one of the validation?

Consider the following model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :field, format: { with: /this/ }
  validates :field, format: { with: /that/ }
end
```

How would the model validate?

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
validates :field, format: {
  with: /some-regex/,
  message: 'A message'
}

validates :field, format: { 
  with: /another-regex/, 
  message: 'Another message'
}
```

I'm guessing from your questions you're concerned about having different messages? You could also construct a more complex regex for the format and roll it into one validation.

Comment: I was wondering what would be required to validate the model. Does the field need to match both validations to be valid or does it only need to match one of them to be valid?

Comment: It requires, both to match, if you want to match only one you should write the regular expression for one validation accordingly.